How to bind visibility of row of ItemsControl
I have ItemsControl. Its items source is binded to observable collection of an object.
Is it possible to bind the visibility of an item (row) ?
<ItemsControl Name="warningItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding WarningItems}" >
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Margin="5, 0, 0, 2" x:Name="warningItemGrid" >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Border BorderBrush="DarkGray" BorderThickness="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" >
                    <Image Name="warningImage" Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="Fill" Opacity="0.25" />
                </Border>

                <TextBlock Name="warningName" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
                           Text="{Binding LocalizedName}" ToolTip="{lex:LocText Key=name,Dict=general,Assembly=WarningPanel}" Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                           Background="Transparent" FontSize="60"/>

                <Button Name="levelButton" Grid.Column="2" Margin="20,2,20,2" ToolTip="{lex:LocText Key=level,Dict=general,Assembly=WarningPanel}" BorderBrush="{Binding LevelBorder}" BorderThickness="2" Focusable="False" Click="WarningLevel_Clicked">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="levelText" Text="{Binding Level}" Foreground="Green" FontSize="60" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Button>

                <Button Name="warningColorButton" Grid.Column="3" Margin="10,1,20,3" ToolTip="{lex:LocText Key=color,Dict=general,Assembly=WarningPanel}" BorderBrush="{Binding ColorBorder}" BorderThickness="2" 
                        Background="{Binding Color}" Visibility="Visible" Focusable="False" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Click="WarningColor_Clicked"></Button>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>

    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Columns="1"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>

